# Is there a disease where having had the disease provides less protection for the future than the vaccination?

Tags: vaccination

Vaccination makes sure that you have anti-bodies so that your immune system has a heads-start once you get infected. If you were infected before, your body also built anti-bodies.

Are there diseases where one knows (or at least has a good reason to believe) that having had the disease provides less protection than the vaccination?

This is a follow-up question to [Is there a benefit of a COVID-19 vaccination if one had COVID-19 before?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25390/2445)

Comment: since a person can have shingles multiple times, and there is a shingles vaccine, I suspect it may be an example. But someone other than me would have to look for the papers.

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate of [this](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/are-there-diseases-for-which-infection-does-not-grant-lasting-immunity-but-a-vac), although there is a slight difference in that that one is asking about no immunity vs. immunity whereas this is asking about weak immunity vs strong immunity.

Comment: Tetanus. Answered in SE Biology april 2020.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few categories:

###### Diseases where infection does not produce immunity

- **Tetanus** infection does not produce immunity. Vaccination with the tetanus toxoid vaccination does ([ref](https://www.cdc.gov/tetanus/clinicians.html)).
- **Respiratory syncytial virus (RSV)** infection does not produce protective immunity; repeat infections are typical. As of May 2023, there's an [RSV vaccine](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-approves-first-respiratory-syncytial-virus-rsv-vaccine) in the US.
- **Malaria** needs continual exposure to the parasite to develop some degree of immunity, and it's probably never sterilizing immunity ([ref](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fimmu.2020.594653/full#h4)). The R21/Matrix-M vaccine is about 77% effective at preventing clinical malaria ([ref](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8121760/)).

###### Diseases where infection results in worse immunity

- **Dengue virus** famously exhibits "[antibody-dependent enhancement (ADE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibody-dependent_enhancement)" of disease, meaning that immunity from infection with one of the four types of the virus results in worse disease after subsequent infection with any of the other types. The Qdenga/TAK-003 vaccine is licensed in some countries and there's no evidence that it causes ADE.

###### Chronic infections

- Diseases that produce chronic infections, such as **HIV** and **hepatitis C**, don't produce useful immunity. Neither of those have vaccines yet, but several are being tested.

###### Highly fatal infections

- **Rabies** and **Ebolavirus disease** have high mortality rates. You might not survive to ever develop natural immunity. Both have vaccines.

Comment: Why do you assume that if there were a vaccine for dengue, it would be more protective than infection? Antibody-dependent enhancement happens in vaccines also - https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34656289/

Comment: I just updated the answer. There's now a licensed dengue vaccine that has no evidence of ADE. The older Dengvaxia might cause ADE but is no longer used in people who haven't been naturally infected.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - even before there was one which didn't, why did you assume that the vaccine won't have ADE?

Comment: Given that natural dengue infection makes subsequent infections with other serotypes *worse*, a dengue vaccine has a low bar to be more protective. It wouldn't be approved if it had known ADE. ("Known" is a key word here. You're right that there might be unknown ADE.)

Comment: You could also add VZV here? There are vaccinations against Herpes zoster available now and the primary infection of course provides no sufficient immunity against shingles